# Mongo $filter entries which have the defined field in aggregation $addFields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, filter, schema

I would like to get the count of array, where each item has value certain field.
So far I have tried different operators e.g `$ne`, `$ifNull` but they don't work.

Here the code example:

```
{
  $addFields: {
    definedItemsCount: {
      $size: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$itemList',
          as: 'item',
          cond: {
            $ne: ['$$item.definedField', null],
          },
        },
      }
    },
  },
},
```

Here is my document `item`

```
{
  title: String,
  definedField: ObjectId
}
```

I need to filter only items with value assigned `definedField`.

So the whole document looks like this, where I need to get the count of `items` with `definedField` being assigned and not null. with `$ne` I get count 2 instead of 1

```
[
  {
    "title": "Title text",
    "items": [
      {
        "title": "some title"
        "definedField": "5ff479fa3dd9d33fc8e3125f",
      },
      {
        "title": "some title"
      }
    ],
    "definedCount": 2,
    "id": "600e081854d922517ccc919e",
    "date": "2021-01-24T23:51:52.820Z",
  }
]
```

**NOTE** I can't use `$match` because the array `items` is field of parental document

Comment: Why are you using $ne if you want a positive match?

Comment: If you want to require that a field is present, use $exists.

Comment: `$exists` doesn't work in `$filter`'s `cond`, as far as about `$ne`, I want `definedField` to be not null, that's why I use `$ne`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok I found a workaround, I have used `$toBool` to convert the `definedField` to boolean and used `$eq` for only `true`, this made the trick inside `$filter` operators `cond ` param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) to check data type of the field, if you have object id in collection then try type is equal to `objectId` the alternative of `objectId` type is 7,

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      definedItemsCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$items",
            as: "item",
            cond: { $eq: [{ $type: "$$item.definedField" }, "objectId"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1RKw5HTa8M0)